What factors influence a movie's IMDb rating?
The Shawshank Redemption (1994) is rated 9.3, which is the highest for a movie.
What does it take for a movie to be rated that high?
For me, movies like Mystic River (2003) are also 9+ rated. I mean, the story, acting, everything in it is top-class; but Mystic River is a 7.9.
There must be something that makes The Shawshank Redemption different from others, and why is Mystic River not 9+?
What makes one movie a 9+ and another 8+ or 7+?

Related: Are IMDb ratings objectively credible?

I don't see much reason to be concerned with IMDb rating, or any rating based on whims of people who perhaps even didn't the films.

And no, The Shawshank Redemption certainly isn't the best film ever made.

@Mithoron then which one is? The Godfather

It's impossible to answer that definitely. Citizen Kane and Vertigo are major contenders, though.

@Mithoron - They didn't the films? Then how did they the score?

@Valorum I mean didn't see, but I think you got it. I think that was a problem on Rotten Tomatoes, so they started to verify if users did see films (at least if they bought tickets). There's this review bombing in particular. People hear some bad rumour and "protest" against something, whether it's real issue or not...

I’m voting to close this question because it is concerned with the workings of a third-party site.

Per the IMDB FAQ,

We take all the individual ratings cast by IMDb registered users and use them to calculate a single rating. We don't use the arithmetic mean (i.e. the sum of all votes divided by the number of votes), although we do display the mean and average votes on the votes breakdown page; instead the rating displayed on a title's page is a weighted average. To display the detailed votes breakdown, click the number of votes located directly below the average IMDb user rating. For an example, see the User rating breakdown for Inside Out.
The IMDb weighted average does not change upon receipt of each new vote, but instead is updated numerous times per day.
A TV series rating is not the weighted average of the ratings of individual episodes. Instead, customers vote separately for the rating of the series as a whole via each title's series page.

So, the short answer is that to get a high rating, the film needs to have lots of IMDB users, especially users who've made lots of other contributions to the site, give it a very high score.

As to why it gets a lower rating, critics have repeatedly mention Mystic River's uneven pacing and downbeat theme, but that's obviously outside the scope of this question.
